# React.js Hooks: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to play with React.js hooks.
Unfortunately, whenever I try to include a component that does contain an usage of the hook,
I do receive the following error message:

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

[image]

***misc/TestComponent/element.js:***

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Used {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
          Click here
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }


export default class TestComponent extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <Example />
        </Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
```

***App.js:***

```js
// Components
import React, { Component, useState, Fragment} from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
 } from 'react-router-dom';
import TestComponent from './components/misc/TestComponent/element.js'
import Body from './components/body/main_view/element.js'
// Static Files
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path={"/news"} component={TestComponent} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: issue at github can help you with that https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14484

Comment: Which version of React are you using? Hooks were only officially added to React 16.8

Comment: I have been using React 16.2
That was an issue. Thanks for help